# jQuery datepicker posting wrong date value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery datepicker to request date input from the user. I have set the local defaults and have it producing the correct date format that I want (dd/mm/yyyy). For some reason this date is posted in the form (mm/dd/yyyy) - how do I ensure that the correct format is posted?

Setting up the defaults:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['en-GB'] = {
        monthNames: [
            'January',
            'February',
            'March',
            'April',
            'May',
            'June',
            'July',
            'August',
            'September',
            'October',
            'November',
            'December'
        ],
        monthNamesShort: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        dayNames: [
            'Sunday',
            'Monday',
            'Tuesday',
            'Wednesday',
            'Thursday',
            'Friday',
            'Saturday'
        ],
        dayNamesShort: [
            'Sun',
            'Mon',
            'Tue',
            'Wed',
            'Thu',
            'Fri',
            'Sat'
        ],
        dayNamesMin: [
            'Su',
            'Mo',
            'Tu',
            'We',
            'Th',
            'Fr',
            'Sa'
        ],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
        firstDay: 1,
        renderer: $.datepicker.defaultRenderer,
        prevText: 'Prev', 
        prevStatus: 'Show the previous month',
        prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', 
        prevJumpStatus: 'Show the previous year',
        nextText: 'Next', 
        nextStatus: 'Show the next month',
        nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', 
        nextJumpStatus: 'Show the next year',
        currentText: 'Current',
        currentStatus: 'Show the current month',
        todayText: 'Today',
        todayStatus: 'Show today\'s month',
        clearText: 'Clear',
        clearStatus: 'Erase the current date',
        closeText: 'Done',
        closeStatus: 'Close without change',
        yearStatus: 'Show a different year',
        monthStatus: 'Show a different month',
        weekText: 'Wk',
        weekStatus: 'Week of the year',
        dayStatus: 'Select DD, M d',
        defaultStatus: 'Select a date',
        isRTL: false
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
});
```

Initialising the datepicker

```
    $(".datepicker").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            onSelect: onSelectHandler
        });
    });
```

Comment: Show us some code. Hard to guess what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just need to do this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Check out [this simple jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DoomHamster/t6WyN/).

EDIT: Looks like your code works for me.  Made a [new fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/DoomHamster/k7eUz/). Also, you don't need to do a .each().  Just $(".datepicker").datepicker({onSelect: onSelectHandler}); should work.

Comment: It's formatting properly on the page. It's the post value which is wrong.

Comment: @me232 Ah! now that is something different.  Is the formatting wrong in the post (can you see this with something like fiddler?) or is your server reformatting it when it receives the post?

Comment: Actually you make a good point. This isn't the exact answer but yes. I am using MVC3 and a certain controller action is doing a post redirect, which is causing a conversion and showing up as a page request in my logs with a backwards date time. I was merely hoping someone would know what the datepicker does when the date is submitted so I could go check that out. Thanks for the suggestion, it's certainly going to lead onto another question about date formatting though

Comment: @me232 The date picker just assigns the string value that is displayed to the input element so it has no control over what happens in the post.  Unless you are doing anything else with the data before the post, then that is how it should be passed to your controller.  Now, you probably have a DateTime object as a param on your ActionResult (or a class that takes a DateTime) so it will just be converted into a DateTime object and all formatting is lost.  You will want to format the DateTime object when you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the UI Jquery, set the correct format when initialize, like this:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Comment: 'dd/mm/yyyy' will result in a date of '09/02/20122012'.  jqUI does not use standard formatting in this regard.

Comment: NP.  I would have given the same answer had I not bothered make a jsFiddle to check.